# Dropdown caret on styled select box disappears on focus

Tags: css, select, input

I've learned that the best way to style a select box is to wrap it in a styled div, so I've done that; my div has a class of select-style. I want the background color of the select box to change on focus, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the dropdown caret (which is a background image) to remain.

Here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
     <head>
        <title>Select Box Styling</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background-color: #FFF;
                font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                padding: 30px;
                margin: 0;
            }

            .select-style {
               width: 240px;
               height: 34px;
               overflow: hidden;
               background: transparent url('dropdown-arrow4.gif') no-repeat right;
               border: 1px solid #8DC63F;
               border-radius: 4px;
            }

            .select-style select {
                background-color: transparent;
                width: 268px;
                padding: 5px;
                font-size: 14px;
                line-height: 1;
                border: 0;
                border-radius: 0;
                height: 34px;
                -webkit-appearance: none;
                font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                color: #222;
            }

            .select-style select:focus,
            .select-style select:active {
                outline: none;
                background-color: #ECF7CB;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="select-style">
            <select>
               <option>The first option</option>
               <option>The second option</option>
               <option>The third option</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You're actually covering the arrow with a background element of a child element. So your `select`, once it's in its `:focus` state, specifies a background color.

The reason the arrow disappears is because the background is no longer transparent (enabling you to see through it and to the dropdown arrow that appears on the parent div.

[here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Morklympious/ty2v5y58/)

I also made the select and its parent the same width so it didn't look awkward when you opened it.

Hope this helps!

EDIT: if you want the arrow to show up while still retaining your green styles, you'll want to apply the `background` property to your `select:focus` CSS selector so that it always has a background image (the dropdown caret) defined regardless of its current state.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried that, and it doesn't work. Fortunately, I figured out how to do it with jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var selectStyle = $('.select-style');

        $('.select-style select').focus(function() {
            $(selectStyle).addClass('select-box-highlight');
        }).blur(function() {
            $(selectStyle).removeClass('select-box-highlight');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Additional CSS:

```
.select-box-highlight {
    outline: none;
    background-color: #ECF7CB;
}
```